Correct understanding of non-commutativity of position operator and momentum operator?
I'm trying to understand more about orbitals and term symbols from the book Orbitals, Terms and States by Malcolm Gerloch. In chapter 2, section 2.3,  page 18, of the book the author writes as follows :

a measurement of the $x$ co-ordinate of a particle manifests the particle in an eigenstate-say $\phi$ - of the associated operator $\hat{x}$. Measuring the value of some other property whose associated operator $\hat{O}$ commutes with $\hat{x}$ would leave the particle in the same state and hence yield a unique eigenvalue of the quantity in question. On the other hand, a measurement of the momentum, associated with a non-commuting operator means that only a value of uncertain reliability is to be found, as we cannot know which eigenstate of  $\hat{p}$ the system would take up at the instant that is already fixed in state  $\phi$ by the simultaneous measurement of the x-coordinate

First, I'm confused by the statement: 'the measurment manifests the particle in an eigenstate $\phi$.
So before measurement, the particle can be in any other state and it is the act of measurement that fixes the state to be $\phi$ ?
Second, it is the nature of the momentum operator (which causes position operator and momentum operator to not commute) that causes the system to change from state $\phi$ to some different state( which is not in the common set of eigenfunctions of position operator and momentum operator)?
Edit : After researching more, I came to the conclusion that measurement does not tell the state before the measurement. So the particle can be in eigenstate different to $\phi$. It is during the act of measurement that gives us the value $\phi$. I'm still not clear on the second  question though.
